# Mouse simulation works really slow. Can it be faster?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, sendmessage

I want to create simple tasker. It should do some clicks on selected area as fast as possible.

I am working on windows7 x64, and this is my code C++

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
bool KeyIsPressed(unsigned char k) {
    USHORT status = GetAsyncKeyState(k);
    return (((status & 0x8000) >> 15) == 1) || ((status & 1) == 1);
}

int main()
{
    HWND target = GetForegroundWindow();
    printf("rdy\n");
    while (true) {
        //  ctrl + T to make the front-most window the targetted window
        if (KeyIsPressed(VK_CONTROL) && KeyIsPressed('T')) {
            target = GetForegroundWindow();
            printf("go\n");

            for (int i= 693 + 13; i < 1100; i+=27)
            {
                for (int j = 59 + 13 ; j < 390; j+=27)
                {
                    SetCursorPos(i, j);
                    SendMessage(target, WM_XBUTTONDOWN, 0, NULL);
                    SendMessage(target, WM_XBUTTONUP, 0,NULL);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see there's a loop, that starts when I press ctrl+T.

---

The operation

```
SetCursorPos(i, j);
SendMessage(target, WM_XBUTTONDOWN, 0, NULL);
SendMessage(target, WM_XBUTTONUP, 0,NULL);
```

is repeated about 180~ times. It takes about 4-5 sec to execute it all.
Is it possbile to make it faster, or those simulating funcions are just slow?

Comment: [You can’t simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513).

Comment: @ IInspectable Unless I'm missing something, he's using SendMessage, not PostMessage.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: use Post or Send Message - no difference in this context (simulate mouse input). SendMessage here even more worse than PostMessage

Comment: @Rb "SendMessage here even more worse than PostMessage" So, there is a difference?

Comment: @NeilButterworth - difference in that `SendMessage` is **synchronous** after every `SendMessage` the application **wait** until `target` handle message, before send new. with `PostMessage` - asynchronous processing - it take not several seconds - but instantly. but the article is about another - both this (Send or Post) not reliable way for simulate mouse or keyboard. in same case this will be worked, in some - no

Comment: @Rb I do know how PostMessage and SendMessage work. I thought you were saying they did the same thing.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I mean another - article called - [You can’t simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513) - if we change `PostMessage` word to `SendMessage` - the key sense of article not changed. this I mean when  say `no difference in *this context*

Comment: if you change `SendMessage` to `PostMessage` in your code - code become really fast. but I not sure are it will be work correct in all cases

Comment: @ IInspectable I have switched from SendMessage to PostMessage, and it works like thunder now. I think this solution is fine for me. This code isn't going to be heavily upgraded, I just need to do some simple task, and the PostMessage function I used works perfectly in this case.

Comment: @Piodo - this because PostMessage not wait until target handle message, unlike SendMessage :)

Comment: @NeilButterworth: `PostMessage` and `SendMessage` perform similar, but different operations. However, it's not interesting what they do. The really interesting part is, what they don't do: Neither one updates the system's internal bookkeeping required for reliable input handling. In that respect both API calls are the same. Had you taken the time to read through the blog post, your contributions to this Q&A may have been distinguishable from noise.

Comment: @Piodo ...you completely misread IInspectable's link. That link said to NOT use `PostMessage()` or `SendMessage()`. The **only** correct way to fake input is `SendInput()`. For most purposes, however, UI Automation is better, though it does not simulate input. What is your end goal? And as for this being a quick and dirty program that's fine with things that accidentally work, what if Microsoft tomorrow decides to just make trying to `PostMessage(WM_KEYDOWN)` an errorless nop, and you install that update? You now waste more time rewriting your Q&D program b/c it wasn't right the 1st time.

Comment: @andlabs That tasker was made to use only once. If I would need some 'bigger' program, I would consider the best options and functions before I would start writing the code (But I had to make some working program fast). In this case that function was fine for me (Solved my problem). Anyway I would like to thank you all for those informations, maybe someday I would be in the need of similiar problem, then I will consider another methods.